# Are `|` and `mknod pipe p` doing the same thing?

Tags: linux, pipe

So obvious thing here the `|` being referred to as the `pipe operator`.

It got me wondering if the pipe operator is just an anonymous pipe.

Whereas `mknod pipe p` is just a named pipe.

Am I correct in thinking this or is there more at work here? Does Linux just create an anonymous hidden pipe file under the covers when you use the pipe operator?

Comment: maybe better for unix SE

Comment: I considered putting it over there but there's already questions about pipes here and we have the pipe and Linux tags

Comment: True, but it's not particularly a coding issue as much as a question about a unix operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A named pipe is a entity in the filesystem (type "p", in front of the file permission) that allows you to transfer data between unix processes. It has a filename and sits in a directory

The pipe operator `|` just connects left `stdout` to right `stdin`, basically.

There's no need for an entry in the filesystem.

Comment: The pipe operator creates an anonymous pipe.  The pipe is a file, but there is no name for it in the file system.  The lack of a name is the reason it's called "anonymous".

Comment: Then it's not a file :/ That's just a magic number.

Comment: It absolutely is a file.   Understanding that the entries in a directory (the names that you see when you run `ls`) are not the files they link to is a fundamental shift in thinking that is necessary to understanding the filesystem.

Comment: Ok, my bad, it's a file. But it's not a dirent, so it can be confusing to be understood by a new user.